# Today Extension Not Positioned Correctly

Tags: widget, ios8, ios-app-extension

I'm developing a Bitcoin Today Extension and for some reason, the control has an offset.  Here's what it currently looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/08WV2.png

As you can see, the button is barely on the screen, and the label isn't on the left side.

My storyboard looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4GC6.png

I've tried settings multiple kinds of constraints, and none of them seem to fix the issue.  I'm not sure what other information I can add, but if you have any questions about the project, I can answer them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To disable the margin you have to use the function widgetMarginInsetsForProposedMarginInsets.

Place this in your code (Swift):

```
func widgetMarginInsetsForProposedMarginInsets(defaultMarginInsets: UIEdgeInsets) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
}
```

Good luck!!

Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NotificationCenter/Reference/NCWidgetProviding_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NCWidgetProviding/widgetMarginInsetsForProposedMarginInsets:

Comment: I've been searching for a solution foreveeeeer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Today extensions have margins by default.

Look there for handling with margins: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NotificationCenter/Reference/NCWidgetProviding_Protocol/index.html